# setting up ssh keys for git hub mac

Tags: github, push

I am following [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) article to set up SSH key from my macbook terminal. However, in step 3 it's asking me to copy the key from id_rsa.pub into clipboard. When I cd ~/.ssh I could not find that file. Instead I have

github_rsa.pub

github_rsa

Both of them have encrypted values. I am not sure where to find that id_rsa.pub file or do I have to use one of the files I mentioned above to copy the key into my clipboard.

I am doing this in order to solve the Permission denied (public token ) issue that is happening which is avoiding me to push code in to my repository.

Thank you

Comment: `cat ~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub | pbcopy`